# Regexp affecting performance of nodejs app. How to replace improve Regexp in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, electron

I am developing an **electron/nodejs** app that uses some **regexps**, two of which are the following :

```
str=  str.replace(/\((.*?)\)/, "");
str= str.match(/\d+/g);
```

I am using these **regexps** inside a function that blocks my electron UI. I then tested the function and I found out that **regexps** are taking much time.

I researched this issue through SO but alas!
[JavaScript regexp performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324757/javascript-regexp-performance) This did not help me.

Edit: I have thousands of strings to be tested by regexp. which creates a very bad impact and even blocks the UI of my electron app!

**Edit2**: At first I did not mention that the electron app was also responsible for loading a lot of photos into the renderer process and rendering them so the issue was not entirely related to the regex.
Another thing to keep in mind is that the app was meant to be used by a very low-end PC (core 2 Duo).

So to overcome this lagging issue I created a background browserWindow in electron and then communicated b/w the main and the background browserWindow using IPC As the background window will start in its process and then split the load between the main and background window.

and it drastically improved the overall app performance and then there was no lagging issue additionally I also implemented lazy loading for images on the front end.

Comment: Promises can help you, create functions where your regex code will executed, This way leads your code non block

Comment: You want to match digit sequences not inside parentheses. If they are paired, you can use `str= str.match(/\d+(?![^()]*\))/g);` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/1pYira/1)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to match digits inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Then replace `!` with `=`, `str.match(/\d+(?=[^()]*\))/g);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ```str.match(/\d+(?=[^()]*\))/g);``` did not improve any performance!

Comment: Then either this regex, or the regex at all, is not the problem, this regex is efficient and fast.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am using asynchronous functions the regexp that you created took more time to execute than mine.

Comment: One regex against two? That does not make sense.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean the regexp that you provide did not make any improvement in performance!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am using the chrome performance tab to record the performance of the code and the profiler pointed out the regexp lines slower. The reqexp line took **2708.0ms** to execute.

Comment: And if you sum `str.replace(/\((.*?)\)/, "")` and `str.match(/\d+/g)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew str.match(/\d+/g) and str.replace(/\((.*?)\)/, "") add up to **6919.0ms**

Comment: See? 3 times as fast.

Comment: The regexp that you provided also take the same time. `str.match(/\d+/g)` and `str.replace(/((.*?))/, "")` are not meant to be replaced by yours. But i want an efficient way of doing the regexp job.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar task on log files with hundreds of thousands of entries.  Unfortunately Node & Electron are not the best choices for this type of task.

While maybe not ideal, the overall solution I was able to use was to create a small application in golang (albeit it could be any other more efficient language) which accepts a simple command line argument and then returns piped data.

After this I was able to use Node/Electron to spawn the child process and call the golang program and grab the response.  I was able to reduce minutes of processing to seconds and still enjoy my wonderful Electron interface.

Sometimes a little creativity goes a long way.  There is not a single language which is stellar in everything, sometimes it is best to pull strengths from each.

Comment: What about creating a background browserWindow in electron and then communicate b/w the main and the background browserWindow using ipc? As the background window will start in its own process and then split the load between the main and bg window?

Comment: @MuhammadTaifKhan You can do that or spawn a specific process for it however in general NodeJS is not a great choice for that type of processing, I love Node and I use it for plenty of things, but mass Regex is not one of it's best qualities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you generation RegExp objects in-place.

This generates two new RegExp(...) and dereference them.

```
str= str.replace(/\((.*?)\)/, "");
str= str.match(/\d+/g);
```

Instead use the following in the module header outside of any function or as class attribute:

```
const ReplaceRegExp = /\((.*?)\)/
const MatchRegExp = /\d+/g;

function x (str:string) {
  str = str.replace(ReplaceRegExp);
  str = str.match(MatchRegExp);
}
```

Comment: V8 will cache these regexp literals internally, so I don't expect this would help. But no harm in measuring it.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately doing that kind of processing on *thousands* of strings is probably not likely to be too efficient regardless of what you do.

I don't have any experience with electron, but you might see if it's possible to use web workers to split up the work among multiple threads and get the heavy processing done faster.  See [Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) from MDN and the top answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574158/number-of-web-workers-limit) for some good info on web workers.

Comment: The regexp issue is related to nodejs. Is there any other   efficient way of doing it? Or only using web workers can solve the problem?

Comment: I've not used node.js before either, but it looks like there might be an equivalent to web workers in it: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html
I'm not sure if this will help you or not, though, it's just an idea.